# Cleanup obsolete SonarQube CE projects

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 9.5 (community edition) and I use Jenkins (2.322 w. sonar plugin v2.14 ) to trigger a Sonar scan at the end of an automated unit tests job (that runs for every new PR).

This results in a number of projects dynamically named:

> projectA-source_branch1

> projectA-source_branch2

> projectA-source_branch3

Is there a way to cleanup projects that are not being used anymore (deleted branches or branches still there but no scans in the last X months)  ?

Comment: Quick question, is this for various jenkinsfiles/pipeline joba or a multibranch pipeline

Answer (score 1):

To run scans for Pull Requests it would be nice to have at least Developer edition where you have specific configurations with automatic clean-up under a single project, using Community I would say the only option you have is to use the SonarQube and BitBucket API(or what you are using), to identify the Pull Requests that are merged and delete the projects based on that.